# simple way to convert parameter pack to array at compile time

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, variadic-templates

is there a simple way to create an `std::array` from a parameter pack at compile time?

```cpp
constexpr auto array = to_array<int>(1, 2, 3, 'a', 5.5f);
```

there are existing solutions:

- helper functions & classes with recursion: not intuitive, difficult to read and not very modern
- C++20's [`std::to_array({...})`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array): sadly it only works when all argument types are equal

what would be a clean way to implement this?

Comment: Note that C++ is backwards compatible, so tagging with 2 language revisions doesn't usually make sense. Unless you're constrained to C++17, you can just remove that tag. Even the C++20 tag can be removed since that's the current language revision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about simply

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Args)> to_array (Args && ... args)
 { return {{ std::forward<Args>(args)... }}; }
```

?

Or, maybe, if you want to add the `static_cast`

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Args)> to_array (Args && ... args)
 { return {{ static_cast<T>(std::forward<Args>(args))... }}; }
```

and using [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) and `auto` return placeholder, you can reduce a little the typewriting

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr auto to_array (Args && ... args)
 { return std::array{ static_cast<T>(std::forward<Args>(args))... }; }
```

Answer (score -1):

A straightforward solution is to expand the parameter pack while increasing an index to copy the values into the array:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr auto to_array(Args&&... args) {
    std::array<T, sizeof...(Args)> result{};

    unsigned ctr = 0u;
    ((result[ctr++] = static_cast<T>(args)), ...);
    return result;
}
```

to show how this function would be callable with an `std::tuple` one can unpack the tuple using an [std::integer_sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence):

```cpp
template<typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr auto to_array(std::tuple<Args...> tuple) {

    auto unpack_tuple = [&]<class Tuple, size_t... Ints>(Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Ints...>) {
        return to_array<T>(std::get<Ints>(tuple)...);
    };

    return unpack_tuple(tuple, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
}
```

and using them:

```cpp
int main() {
    constexpr auto a = to_array<int>(std::tuple(5, 3, 'a', 1.0));
    constexpr auto b = to_array<int>(5, 3, 'a', 1.0);

    static_assert(a == b);
}
```

---

used headers:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
```